# mlpack error while building

Tags: package, ubuntu-14.04, mlpack

I get the following error after I install libmlpack-dev, include it in my program and compile it.

```
/usr/include/mlpack/methods/kmeans/kmeans_impl.hpp: In member function ‘void mlpack::kmeans::KMeans<MetricType, InitialPartitionPolicy, EmptyClusterPolicy, LloydStepType, MatType>::Cluster(const MatType&, size_t, arma::mat&, bool)’:
/usr/include/mlpack/methods/kmeans/kmeans_impl.hpp:178:20: error: call of overloaded ‘isnan(double&)’ is ambiguous
 if (isnan(cNorm) || isinf(cNorm))
                ^
/usr/include/mlpack/methods/kmeans/kmeans_impl.hpp:178:20: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
             from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:25
```

Can someone suggest how to solve this.

P.S : I had asked this in 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/847048/mlpack-error-while-building

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with mlpack on older versions of Ubuntu.  If you upgrade Ubuntu to a newer version and update the mlpack package the issue should be solved.  But if you are unable to do that, you can directly edit the file `/usr/include/mlpack/methods/kmeans/kmeans_impl.hpp` so that the line

```
if (isnan(cNorm) || isinf(cNorm))
```

is changed to

```
if (std::isnan(cNorm) || std::isinf(cNorm))
```

and this should fix the issue.